# Is there any benefit from using SHA-512 over SHA-256 when AES just truncates it anyway?

Tags: aes, key-derivation, sha-256, key-size, sha-512

I am still not very clear on how AES-256-CBC can use SHA-512 bit keys, but I assume that it just truncates the 512bit hash down to 256bit.
In software like GnuPG and OpenPGP, is there any real benefit using a SHA-512 key over a SHA-256 key with the AES-256-CBC block cipher?

Comment: Who says that AES256 has to use a key generated from SHA2 (from what data)? Depending on the use case and other details, this might be very bad.

Comment: Other than that, CBC needs an IV.

Comment: It sounds like you're *actually* asking why AES-256-CBC might be paired with SHA-512. That doesn't mean SHA-512 is used to generate keys. It may also be used as an HMAC to authenticate the ciphertext.

Comment: Note: **PGP** (including implementations like GnuPG) **never uses CBC** mode of AES nor any other suppported cipher, although as answered it can use either SHA-256 or SHA-512 (and for that matter SHA-224 and SHA-384 and more) for password-based key derivation

Answer (score 14):

SHA-512 has both a larger internal state and a higher number of rounds than SHA-256 - which means that it provides a higher bit strength. Somewhat surprisingly it may also *outperform* SHA-256, as it uses 64 bit word size, which works best on 64 bit processors. You can see a good comparison table [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions)

If less bits are required from SHA-512 then they are generally just taken from the left of the output (it doesn't matter which bits are used, this is just convention). There are also specialized constructs such as SHA-512/256 that use different initial values. This should be used in case the leakage of a partial hash is a problem within the specific protocol.

That said there are no attacks on SHA-256 that come close to breaking that particular algorithm, so it can still be used with some kind of confidence.

---

There is no such thing as a SHA-256 or SHA-512 key. SHA-2 may be used to derive keys though, for instance using HKDF. For key derivation it is best to use the hash as part of a HMAC function to create a PRF.

[As deviantfan commented](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/is-there-any-benefit-from-using-sha-512-over-sha-256#comment94567_41476), CBC requires an IV. The additional output of the SHA-512 function could be used to deliver those additional 128 bits.

---

For GPG specifically, RFC 4880: OpenPGP Message Format specifies [in section 3.7.1.1: Simple S2K](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.1):

> If the hash size is greater than the session key size, the high-order (leftmost) octets of the hash are used as the key.

This is also the method used for Salted S2K and Iterated and Salted S2K as those expand the Simple S2K function.

---

Note that there is a specialized SHA-512 version called SHA-512/256 standardized by NIST, which let you use a version of SHA-512 with reduced output. It uses different constants which could fend of some attacks as the start of a hash may tell an attacker something about the full hash. Obviously it therefore produces different output than (the leftmost bytes of) SHA-512. SHA-512/256 should be used instead of SHA-512 in new protocols *if* your target platforms support it.

Comment: So, even though it truncates a SHA-512 hash down to the 256 bits that AES CBC needs, you would still pick SHA-512? And I was right in saying AES simply chops the derived key down to the requirement?

Comment: 1. Depends on the platforms. For a 64 bit high end platforms I'd probably use SHA-512 or one of the 3 derivatives, yes. If a 32 bit or lower platform is also required, keep to SHA-256. 2. AES is a block cipher. It *requires* a 128, 192 or 256 bits. It doesn't do any cutting etc. out of itself. It depends on the protocol how the key is derived. Any AES implementation that accepts any other key size than the ones above should not be used (hi, mcrypt).

Comment: Well with implementations in GPG, it uses s2k or string-to-text. You are able to configure it to use AES-256 with SHA-512. Does this mean that it is deriving the key from the user password over many iterations. Then the result is still 512 bits, how does AES-256 use the 512bit derived key?

Comment: For that specific protocol, RFC 4880 specifies this directly: "If the hash size is greater than the session key size, the high-order (leftmost) octets of the hash are used as the key." So the protocol follows common practice, yes. (I think you meant string-to-key instead of string-to-text by the way.)

Comment: Yes, I meant string-to-text. If that protocol splits the hash size to match the block size, would you still use SHA-512 or save OpenPGP truncating the hash by using SHA-256?

Comment: Neither option is bad, but unless you need to use embedded processors I'd still prefer SHA-512 if I'd the choice. But it's not a huge difference; just choose one and continue to more interesting topics.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there are any 64-bit CPUs where SHA-512 outperforms SHA-256.  Most 64-bit ISAs have efficient 32-bit operations, including rotate.  e.g. compiler output for 32-bit rotates on x86-64, ARM64, and MIPS64:  https://godbolt.org/g/Svk2aF.   One exception is Alpha, which only has 64-bit ops.  In that case, 64-bit ADD and bitwise operations still produce the correct low 32 bits [regardless of garbage in the high bits](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34377711/224132), and 32-bit rotation by N can be done in 4 instructions: http://gorton-machine.org/rick/alpha/alpha.html#rot32_R_N

Comment: Also, for x86 CPUs, [Intel SHA extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692386/are-there-in-x86-any-instructions-to-accelerate-sha-sha1-2-256-512-encoding) accelerate SHA1 and SHA-256, but unfortunately not SHA-512.

Comment: **Oops, even though SHA-512 has more rounds, it processes twice at much data at once**.  So yes, it's definitely faster in MB/s on most 64-bit CPUs!  Not because 64-bit ops are faster, but because they're the same speed as 32-bit ops.  For example, [this implementation and benchmark](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-sha2-hashes-in-x86-assembly) found 207.6MB/s for SHA-512 vs. 133.3MB/s for SHA-256, single-threaded on a Core2 2.4GHz.

Comment: @PeterCordes Data rate doesn't matter for password hashing, but how long one hash evaluation takes (think of different block sizes). It sounds like that is about the same. This changes when considering HMAC, but that's a different situation. Anyway, for password hashing speed is much less relevant (because the total time required has to be adjusted anyway). I agree with Maarten Bodewes, just choose one and move on - it doesn't make much of a difference on current hardware.